# Перезапись данных текстового файла на сервере (например GoogleDisc или любой другой с прямой ссылкой) - JAVA

Tags: java

Друзья приветствую!
Подскажите пожалуйста как решить такой вопрос, если его вообще можно решить не нарушая никаких норм.
У меня есть тектовый файл на GoogleDisc (файл для личного пользования). Я беру данные из него и заношу в List. Затем я некоторые данные обновляю - создаю новый List на основе комбинирования информации из файла и обновлений. Данные нового List я хочу вернуть туда откуда я взял данные оригинального текстовика, т.е. переписать текстовик на GoogleDisc данными из нового List.

Вопрос: Вот часть кода, которая, как мне кажется должна бы делать то что я хочу. Компиляция проходит успешно, однако данные файла не обновились:

```
public static void uploadOutputList (ArrayList<String> listToUpload, String address) throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL(address);
    URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
    urlc.setDoOutput(true);

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlc.getOutputStream()));
 
    for (int i = 0; i < listToUpload.size(); i++) {
        out.write(listToUpload.get(i));
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();       
}
```

Comment: разные сервисы имеют свое API и нужно пользоваться им. Если бы можно было просто так залить файл назад... а ещё и без имени-паролья... подобные сервисы уже бы давно ушли бы в небытие

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java